# ReactPress Manual Mode: Wordpress needs access to npm

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I am trying to host a pre-existing react website on 101domains.com using wordpress and reactpress, but I am currently stuck in Manual Mode for reactpress. I have uploaded my build folder to wordpress, but I cannot start the server to host the react app. Here is the error:

```
Currently you are in Manual Mode, (this means, you can create React apps only in your command line) because:
Your WordPress installation needs access to "npm 6" or higher to create React apps from the admin interface. However you can go to the app directory and use create-react-app from there.
```

I am trying to figure out how to give WordPress access to npm, but I am new to WP, so I am quite lost. Any advice would be nice!

Answer (score 0):

To use ReactPress with an existing create-react-app. You need to build it with ReactPress on a local WordPress system. I recommend localWP.

Install ReactPress there, copy your whole create-react-app into the apps directory, add a page slug from the WP admin and update the dev environment.

Then build your React app from the command line. Now you can push that build to your live website. There you must choose the identical page slug for your React app. Then it should show under your chosen page slug.